# Regex for folder path without file name

Tags: javascript, angular, regex

I want to validate a text field for input as folder path only, It should not accept the filename. Can someone please help me with the regex pattern in javascript?

eg.

`folder1/folder2/folder3` => valid

`folder1/folder2/filename.txt1` => invalid

Comment: `folder3` could be a file or a directory on macs. Do you only want to block specific extensions?

Comment: "please help me" typically means you've got a start and need help with a specific part. If you want someone to write the regex for you, that's a bit much to ask volunteers to do, don't you think?

Comment: sorry, I tried many patterns but they accept filenames too. I want to block all files with any extension, especially, .txt, .csv, .xlsx, .doc should not accept

Comment: Extensions are not required for files though. Do you care about that? Something like `^[\w/]+$` would work but would fail for `folder/file` where `file` is a `csv` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below RegEx will validate that the string is of the form `folder1/folder2/folder3`

```js
const regExp = /^[\w+\/]+$/;

console.log(regExp.test('folder/folder/folder'));
console.log(regExp.test('folder/folder/text.txt'));
```

Answer (score 1):

This function assumes files will always have extensions. Instead of regex, it uses a basic split and checks to see if the last element has a period. However, it isn't perfect as directories can also have a period. So it might work if you are handling the folder structure etc on server side.

```js
var path1 = "/f/d/a/1.txt";
var path2 = "/f/d/a";

function validatePath(str){
  temp = str.split("/");
  return (temp[temp.length-1].indexOf(".") > 0);
}

console.log(validatePath(path1));
console.log(validatePath(path2));
```

Comment: thank you so much, everyone, I really appreciate that you all answered my small question

Answer (score 1):

Solution with Regex. It doesn't work wit paths like `../`, `./` and domains.

```js
    var path1 = "folder1/folder2/filename.txt";
    var path2 = "folder1/folder2/folder3";
    
    
    function validatePath(str){
      let re = new RegExp('^[^.]+$')
      return re.test(str);
    }
    
    console.log(validatePath(path1));
    console.log(validatePath(path2));
```